# Anypoint Studio ERROR despite everything working correctly

Tags: mule, mulesoft, anypoint-studio

I have created endpoint in Mule Soft which contains data from 3 separate APIs (2 REST and 1 SOAP), but despite working correctly it return an error:

```
ERROR 2021-12-22 00:24:23,483 [[MuleRuntime].uber.04: [projekt_isi].Found_course_response.BLOCKING @3d5f454f] [processor: Found_course_response/processors/6; event: 1dd95df0-62b5-11ec-902a-d481d75d7926] org.mule.soap.internal.generator.attachment.AttachmentResponseEnricher: Could not close XMLEventWriter
```

Because this request takes pretty long time I am guessing that this ERROR causes it, but all I found on internet was that it is problem with XML conversion that is supposedly already resolved. Have you ever encountered such problem? It is strange to especially since I get correct JSON response which contains both JSON responses from REST APIs as well as converted XML response from SOAP API.

Here is how the Flow looks like:

EDIT: As requested here is whole Error:

```
ERROR 2021-12-22 00:24:14,556 [[MuleRuntime].uber.05: [projekt_isi].Found_course_response.BLOCKING @3d5f454f] [processor: Found_course_response/processors/6; event: 1c280470-62b5-11ec-902a-d481d75d7926] org.mule.soap.internal.generator.attachment.AttachmentResponseEnricher: Could not close XMLEventWriter
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Trying to write END_DOCUMENT when document has no root (ie. trying to output empty document).
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.throwOutputError(BaseStreamWriter.java:1589) ~[woodstox-core-6.2.6.jar:6.2.6]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.reportNwfStructure(BaseStreamWriter.java:1618) ~[woodstox-core-6.2.6.jar:6.2.6]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter._finishDocument(BaseStreamWriter.java:1444) ~[woodstox-core-6.2.6.jar:6.2.6]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.close(BaseStreamWriter.java:247) ~[woodstox-core-6.2.6.jar:6.2.6]
    at org.codehaus.stax2.ri.Stax2EventWriterImpl.close(Stax2EventWriterImpl.java:183) ~[stax2-api-4.2.1.jar:4.2.1]
    at org.mule.soap.internal.generator.attachment.AttachmentResponseEnricher$CustomXMLEventWriter.close(AttachmentResponseEnricher.java:288) ~[mule-soap-engine-1.6.4.jar:?]
    at org.mule.soap.internal.generator.attachment.AttachmentResponseEnricher.processXmlStream(AttachmentResponseEnricher.java:158) ~[mule-soap-engine-1.6.4.jar:?]
    at org.mule.soap.internal.generator.attachment.AttachmentResponseEnricher.enrich(AttachmentResponseEnricher.java:97) ~[mule-soap-engine-1.6.4.jar:?]
    at org.mule.soap.internal.generator.SoapResponseGenerator.generate(SoapResponseGenerator.java:57) ~[mule-soap-engine-1.6.4.jar:?]
    at org.mule.soap.internal.client.AbstractSoapCxfClient.consume(AbstractSoapCxfClient.java:131) ~[mule-soap-engine-1.6.4.jar:?]
    at org.mule.extension.ws.internal.connection.WscSoapClient.consume(WscSoapClient.java:56) ~[mule-wsc-connector-1.6.6-mule-plugin.jar:?]
    at org.mule.extension.ws.internal.ConsumeOperation.consume(ConsumeOperation.java:92) ~[mule-wsc-connector-1.6.6-mule-plugin.jar:?]
    at org.mule.extension.ws.internal.ConsumeOperation$consume$MethodComponentExecutor.execute(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.execution.GeneratedMethodComponentExecutor.execute(GeneratedMethodComponentExecutor.java:98) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.4.0-20211026.jar:4.4.0-20211026]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.execution.CompletableMethodOperationExecutor.doExecute(CompletableMethodOperationExecutor.java:29) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.4.0-20211026.jar:4.4.0-20211026]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.execution.AbstractCompletableMethodOperationExecutor.execute(AbstractCompletableMethodOperationExecutor.java:63) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.4.0-20211026.jar:4.4.0-20211026]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.DefaultExecutionMediator.executeCommand(DefaultExecutionMediator.java:232) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.4.0-20211026.jar:4.4.0-20211026]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.DefaultExecutionMediator.executeWithInterceptors(DefaultExecutionMediator.java:216) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.4.0-20211026.jar:4.4.0-20211026]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.DefaultExecutionMediator.lambda$execute$1(DefaultExecutionMediator.java:135) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.4.0-20211026.jar:4.4.0-20211026]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.DefaultExecutionMediator.lambda$new$0(DefaultExecutionMediator.java:72) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.4.0-20211026.jar:4.4.0-20211026]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.DefaultExecutionMediator.withExecutionTemplate(DefaultExecutionMediator.java:316) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.4.0-20211026.jar:4.4.0-20211026]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.DefaultExecutionMediator.execute(DefaultExecutionMediator.java:134) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.4.0-20211026.jar:4.4.0-20211026]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.ComponentMessageProcessor.executeOperation(ComponentMessageProcessor.java:588) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.4.0-20211026.jar:4.4.0-20211026]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.ComponentMessageProcessor.prepareAndExecuteOperation(ComponentMessageProcessor.java:811) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.4.0-20211026.jar:4.4.0-20211026]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.ComponentMessageProcessor.lambda$onEventSynchronous$16(ComponentMessageProcessor.java:490) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.4.0-20211026.jar:4.4.0-20211026]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.ComponentMessageProcessor.onEventSynchronous(ComponentMessageProcessor.java:497) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.4.0-20211026.jar:4.4.0-20211026]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.ComponentMessageProcessor.lambda$null$6(ComponentMessageProcessor.java:405) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.4.0-20211026.jar:4.4.0-20211026]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:482) [reactor-core-3.2.22.RELEASE.jar:3.2.22.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:287) [reactor-core-3.2.22.RELEASE.jar:3.2.22.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:496) [reactor-core-3.2.22.RELEASE.jar:3.2.22.RELEASE]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain$2.onNext(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:477) [mule-core-4.4.0-20211026.jar:4.4.0-20211026]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain$2.onNext(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:472) [mule-core-4.4.0-20211026.jar:4.4.0-20211026]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxHide.java:127) [reactor-core-3.2.22.RELEASE.jar:3.2.22.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:204) [reactor-core-3.2.22.RELEASE.jar:3.2.22.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:351) [reactor-core-3.2.22.RELEASE.jar:3.2.22.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSubscribeOnValue$ScheduledScalar.run(FluxSubscribeOnValue.java:178) [reactor-core-3.2.22.RELEASE.jar:3.2.22.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:50) [reactor-core-3.2.22.RELEASE.jar:3.2.22.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:27) [reactor-core-3.2.22.RELEASE.jar:3.2.22.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_282]
    at org.mule.service.scheduler.internal.AbstractRunnableFutureDecorator.doRun(AbstractRunnableFutureDecorator.java:113) [mule-service-scheduler-1.4.0/:?]
    at org.mule.service.scheduler.internal.RunnableFutureDecorator.run(RunnableFutureDecorator.java:54) [mule-service-scheduler-1.4.0/:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_282]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_282]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_282]
ERROR 2021-12-22 00:24:23,483 [[MuleRuntime].uber.04: [projekt_isi].Found_course_response.BLOCKING @3d5f454f] [processor: Found_course_response/processors/6; event: 1dd95df0-62b5-11ec-902a-d481d75d7926] org.mule.soap.internal.generator.attachment.AttachmentResponseEnricher: Could not close XMLEventWriter
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Trying to write END_DOCUMENT when document has no root (ie. trying to output empty document).
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.throwOutputError(BaseStreamWriter.java:1589) ~[woodstox-core-6.2.6.jar:6.2.6]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.reportNwfStructure(BaseStreamWriter.java:1618) ~[woodstox-core-6.2.6.jar:6.2.6]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter._finishDocument(BaseStreamWriter.java:1444) ~[woodstox-core-6.2.6.jar:6.2.6]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.close(BaseStreamWriter.java:247) ~[woodstox-core-6.2.6.jar:6.2.6]
    at org.codehaus.stax2.ri.Stax2EventWriterImpl.close(Stax2EventWriterImpl.java:183) ~[stax2-api-4.2.1.jar:4.2.1]
    at org.mule.soap.internal.generator.attachment.AttachmentResponseEnricher$CustomXMLEventWriter.close(AttachmentResponseEnricher.java:288) ~[mule-soap-engine-1.6.4.jar:?]
    at org.mule.soap.internal.generator.attachment.AttachmentResponseEnricher.processXmlStream(AttachmentResponseEnricher.java:158) ~[mule-soap-engine-1.6.4.jar:?]
    at org.mule.soap.internal.generator.attachment.AttachmentResponseEnricher.enrich(AttachmentResponseEnricher.java:97) ~[mule-soap-engine-1.6.4.jar:?]
    at org.mule.soap.internal.generator.SoapResponseGenerator.generate(SoapResponseGenerator.java:57) ~[mule-soap-engine-1.6.4.jar:?]
    at org.mule.soap.internal.client.AbstractSoapCxfClient.consume(AbstractSoapCxfClient.java:131) ~[mule-soap-engine-1.6.4.jar:?]
    at org.mule.extension.ws.internal.connection.WscSoapClient.consume(WscSoapClient.java:56) ~[mule-wsc-connector-1.6.6-mule-plugin.jar:?]
    at org.mule.extension.ws.internal.ConsumeOperation.consume(ConsumeOperation.java:92) ~[mule-wsc-connector-1.6.6-mule-plugin.jar:?]
    at org.mule.extension.ws.internal.ConsumeOperation$consume$MethodComponentExecutor.execute(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.execution.GeneratedMethodComponentExecutor.execute(GeneratedMethodComponentExecutor.java:98) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.4.0-20211026.jar:4.4.0-20211026]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.execution.CompletableMethodOperationExecutor.doExecute(CompletableMethodOperationExecutor.java:29) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.4.0-20211026.jar:4.4.0-20211026]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.execution.AbstractCompletableMethodOperationExecutor.execute(AbstractCompletableMethodOperationExecutor.java:63) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.4.0-20211026.jar:4.4.0-20211026]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.DefaultExecutionMediator.executeCommand(DefaultExecutionMediator.java:232) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.4.0-20211026.jar:4.4.0-20211026]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.DefaultExecutionMediator.executeWithInterceptors(DefaultExecutionMediator.java:216) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.4.0-20211026.jar:4.4.0-20211026]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.DefaultExecutionMediator.lambda$execute$1(DefaultExecutionMediator.java:135) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.4.0-20211026.jar:4.4.0-20211026]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.DefaultExecutionMediator.lambda$new$0(DefaultExecutionMediator.java:72) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.4.0-20211026.jar:4.4.0-20211026]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.DefaultExecutionMediator.withExecutionTemplate(DefaultExecutionMediator.java:316) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.4.0-20211026.jar:4.4.0-20211026]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.DefaultExecutionMediator.execute(DefaultExecutionMediator.java:134) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.4.0-20211026.jar:4.4.0-20211026]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.ComponentMessageProcessor.executeOperation(ComponentMessageProcessor.java:588) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.4.0-20211026.jar:4.4.0-20211026]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.ComponentMessageProcessor.prepareAndExecuteOperation(ComponentMessageProcessor.java:811) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.4.0-20211026.jar:4.4.0-20211026]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.ComponentMessageProcessor.lambda$onEventSynchronous$16(ComponentMessageProcessor.java:490) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.4.0-20211026.jar:4.4.0-20211026]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.ComponentMessageProcessor.onEventSynchronous(ComponentMessageProcessor.java:497) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.4.0-20211026.jar:4.4.0-20211026]
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.operation.ComponentMessageProcessor.lambda$null$6(ComponentMessageProcessor.java:405) ~[mule-module-extensions-support-4.4.0-20211026.jar:4.4.0-20211026]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:482) [reactor-core-3.2.22.RELEASE.jar:3.2.22.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:287) [reactor-core-3.2.22.RELEASE.jar:3.2.22.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:496) [reactor-core-3.2.22.RELEASE.jar:3.2.22.RELEASE]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain$2.onNext(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:477) [mule-core-4.4.0-20211026.jar:4.4.0-20211026]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain$2.onNext(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:472) [mule-core-4.4.0-20211026.jar:4.4.0-20211026]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxHide.java:127) [reactor-core-3.2.22.RELEASE.jar:3.2.22.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:204) [reactor-core-3.2.22.RELEASE.jar:3.2.22.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:351) [reactor-core-3.2.22.RELEASE.jar:3.2.22.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSubscribeOnValue$ScheduledScalar.run(FluxSubscribeOnValue.java:178) [reactor-core-3.2.22.RELEASE.jar:3.2.22.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:50) [reactor-core-3.2.22.RELEASE.jar:3.2.22.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:27) [reactor-core-3.2.22.RELEASE.jar:3.2.22.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_282]
    at org.mule.service.scheduler.internal.AbstractRunnableFutureDecorator.doRun(AbstractRunnableFutureDecorator.java:113) [mule-service-scheduler-1.4.0/:?]
    at org.mule.service.scheduler.internal.RunnableFutureDecorator.run(RunnableFutureDecorator.java:54) [mule-service-scheduler-1.4.0/:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_282]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_282]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_282]
```

And here is XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core" xmlns:wsc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/wsc"
    xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/wsc http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/wsc/current/mule-wsc.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_config" doc:name="HTTP_Listener_config" doc:id="70a95691-a977-48ff-8439-79a5d2fc7bb7" >
        <http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="88" />
    </http:listener-config>
    <wsc:config name="Web_Service_Consumer_Config" doc:name="Web Service Consumer Config" doc:id="0a403287-6d01-45e1-bb5f-47ffcc7a5f71" >
        <wsc:connection wsdlLocation="https://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/NumberConversion.wso?wsdl" service="NumberConversion" port="NumberConversionSoap" address="https://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/NumberConversion.wso">
            <wsc:web-service-security actor="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next" />
        </wsc:connection>
    </wsc:config>
    <http:request-config name="First_REST_API" doc:name="HTTP Request configuration" doc:id="84f17cc0-eb86-4c2a-b122-7d5f22781423" basePath="https://random-data-api.com/api/number/random_number?size=1" >
        <http:request-connection protocol="HTTPS" />
    </http:request-config>
    <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_configuration" doc:name="HTTP Request configuration" doc:id="93a99571-d4d7-43c3-9505-26f2a56e97b3">
        <http:request-connection protocol="HTTPS" />
    </http:request-config>
    <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_configuration1" doc:name="HTTP Request configuration" doc:id="282ae316-cee6-4305-ae58-283858258ec6">
        <http:request-connection protocol="HTTPS" host="random-data-api.com"/>
    </http:request-config>
    <http:request-config name="Local_REST_API_Config" doc:name="HTTP Request configuration" doc:id="6cf97fb4-f770-44fb-b450-4ccccf29db1a" >
        <http:request-connection host="localhost" port="1234" />
    </http:request-config>
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_config1" doc:name="HTTP Listener config" doc:id="0a9a912a-50df-4963-b17a-f61f53aaa656" >
        <http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="82" readTimeout="3000"/>
    </http:listener-config>
    <flow name="get_Price_text" doc:id="b4f797c1-ef45-4af5-942f-7c020f3faa31" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="0143fc37-b5c0-45f9-9338-e901cdbfc43c" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/api/courses/find/"/>
        <http:request method="GET" doc:name="Call REST API" doc:id="a8fd827c-8648-4d4e-8db4-7107ae1b0be4" path="/api/number/random_number?size=1" config-ref="HTTP_Request_configuration1"/>
        <set-variable value="#[output application/java
&#10;---
&#10;payload.decimal]" doc:name="Set Variable" doc:id="686acb85-627d-43fa-953f-713244b070fb" variableName="price_number"/>
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="3b35fcc5-3dc0-4889-93a3-c65dc38bc6bf">
            <ee:message>
                <ee:set-payload><![CDATA[output application/xml
---
{
            NumberToDollars @(xmlns: "http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/"): {
                dNum: payload.decimal
}
}]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
        <wsc:consume operation="NumberToDollars" doc:name="Consume" doc:id="6e83b178-f444-46fc-bdff-f96000235ff9" config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer_Config"/>
        <set-variable value="#[output application/java
&#10;ns ns0 http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/
&#10;---
&#10;payload.body.ns0#NumberToDollarsResponse.ns0#NumberToDollarsResult]" doc:name="Set Variable" doc:id="1e6d7716-93a5-4036-828e-6b1655127c85" variableName="price_string"/>
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="7bc88477-1057-4123-bc9e-fb1bcca7b174" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    price_numeric: vars.price_number[0],
    price_string: vars.price_string
}]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
        <set-variable value="#[output application/json
&#10;---
&#10;{
&#10;   price_numeric: vars.price_number[0],
&#10;   price_string: vars.price_string
&#10;}]" doc:name="Set Variable" doc:id="330aac85-6da7-4775-b366-6e3fd79436f2" variableName="price_JSON"/>
    </flow>
    <flow name="projekt_isiFlow" doc:id="7fed68f6-ae9d-4a04-ad71-673b1f3f47fb" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Copy_of_Listener" doc:id="5422cb86-c49b-4fc5-b2fa-48f44abb574d" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/api/courses/find/{id}" />
        <set-payload value="#[attributes.uriParams.id]" doc:name="Set Payload" doc:id="5a12884f-b2d3-4979-b9ae-66935b200677" />
        <http:request method="GET" doc:name="Copy_of_Call Custom REST API " doc:id="fc88359a-c925-4a9d-b0ab-508be1fd619e" config-ref="Local_REST_API_Config" path="/api/courses/find/{id}" outputMimeType="application/json">
            <http:body><![CDATA[{}]]></http:body>
            <http:uri-params ><![CDATA[#[output application/java
---
{
 id: payload
}]]]></http:uri-params>
        </http:request>
        <set-variable value='#[output application/json
&#10;---
&#10;{
&#10;   isPublished: payload.isPublished,
&#10;   tags: payload.tags map ( tag , indexOfTag ) -&gt; tag,
&#10;   "_id": payload."_id",
&#10;   dishName: payload.dishName,
&#10;   category: payload.category,
&#10;   author: payload.author,
&#10;   ingredients: payload.ingredients map ( ingredient , indexOfIngredient ) -&gt; {
&#10;       "_id": ingredient."_id",
&#10;       quantity: ingredient.quantity,
&#10;       unit: ingredient.unit,
&#10;       description: ingredient.description
&#10;   },
&#10;   cookingTime: payload.cookingTime,
&#10;   sourceUrl: payload.sourceUrl,
&#10;   imageUrl: payload.imageUrl,
&#10;   price: payload.price,
&#10;   date: payload.date,
&#10;   "__v": payload."__v"
&#10;}]' doc:name="Set Variable" doc:id="7a7fa41c-5e5e-438c-b4f3-fb142c8d83a9" variableName="results" mimeType="application/json"/>
    </flow>
    <flow name="Found_course_response" doc:id="e4042d03-603f-41c5-91a1-e12c2992d75e" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener with URI ID" doc:id="b1ecf442-8975-4385-b11b-cac1677613ef" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config1" path="/api/courses/find/{id}" />
        <set-payload value="#[attributes.uriParams.id]" doc:name="Set payload with URI ID" doc:id="8499152a-c601-488c-8cbd-2a081e38b20f" />
        <http:request method="GET" doc:name="REST API request for Course with ID" doc:id="d17382dd-e848-44fc-b4e4-495991b61325" config-ref="Local_REST_API_Config" path="/api/courses/find/{id}" outputMimeType="application/json">
            <http:body><![CDATA[{}]]></http:body>
            <http:uri-params><![CDATA[#[output application/java
---
{
 id: payload
}]]]></http:uri-params>
        </http:request>
        <set-variable value='#[output application/json
&#10;---
&#10;{
&#10;   isPublished: payload.isPublished,
&#10;   tags: payload.tags map ( tag , indexOfTag ) -&gt; tag,
&#10;   "_id": payload."_id",
&#10;   dishName: payload.dishName,
&#10;   category: payload.category,
&#10;   author: payload.author,
&#10;   ingredients: payload.ingredients map ( ingredient , indexOfIngredient ) -&gt; {
&#10;       "_id": ingredient."_id",
&#10;       quantity: ingredient.quantity,
&#10;       unit: ingredient.unit,
&#10;       description: ingredient.description
&#10;   },
&#10;   cookingTime: payload.cookingTime,
&#10;   sourceUrl: payload.sourceUrl,
&#10;   imageUrl: payload.imageUrl,
&#10;   price: payload.price,
&#10;   date: payload.date,
&#10;   "__v": payload."__v"
&#10;}]' doc:name="Set variable with response JSON" doc:id="f712c7d0-65a8-48ab-a7a4-088ba23c9956" variableName="results" mimeType="application/json" />
        <http:request method="GET" doc:name="Call REST API for random number" doc:id="90a7f6f5-aeba-4b28-a5af-43dcd4b87e16" config-ref="HTTP_Request_configuration1" path="/api/number/random_number?size=1" />
        <set-variable value="#[output application/java
&#10;---
&#10;payload.decimal]" doc:name="Set Variable with REST API response " doc:id="5e409a00-0968-4cc7-a24e-da4efb9b2e03" variableName="price_number"/>
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform response to XML" doc:id="3a0f5690-a8ca-4e4d-9a8a-71645cf0940f" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[output application/xml
---
{
            NumberToDollars @(xmlns: "http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/"): {
                dNum: payload.decimal
}
}]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
        <wsc:consume operation="NumberToDollars" doc:name="Call SOAP API with payload for string version of number" doc:id="0a8622d2-98ab-4114-8902-57bcdc2f58ba" config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer_Config" />
        <set-variable value="#[output application/java
&#10;ns ns0 http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/
&#10;---
&#10;payload.body.ns0#NumberToDollarsResponse.ns0#NumberToDollarsResult]" doc:name="Set Variable with SOAP API response" doc:id="25495ffe-b5ef-49de-a9c0-d4db668a58a6" variableName="price_string"/>
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform all responses into one JSON" doc:id="10c1c874-782b-4c4c-84d4-bb14bf3e50a7" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    isPublished: vars.results.isPublished,
    tags: vars.results.tags map ( tag , indexOfTag ) -> tag,
    "_id": vars.results."_id",
    dishName: vars.results.dishName,
    category: vars.results.category,
    author: vars.results.author,
    ingredients: vars.results.ingredients map ( ingredient , indexOfIngredient ) -> {
        "_id": ingredient."_id",
        quantity: ingredient.quantity,
        unit: ingredient.unit,
        description: ingredient.description
    },
    cookingTime: vars.results.cookingTime,
    sourceUrl: vars.results.sourceUrl,
    imageUrl: vars.results.imageUrl,
    price: vars.price_number[0],
    priceText: vars.price_string,   
    date: vars.results.date,
    "__v": vars.results."__v"
}]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

[image: Here is how the Flow looks like]

Comment: Please provide details to understand the issue and be able to help you. The screenshot provides very little insight onto what the flow does. Instead paste the flow as XML text. Add versions of Studio, Mule and any connector in the flow. The error message may contain more details of the error and its location in the flow. If there are details please add them too. Even so, defining the Java property mule.verbose.exceptions=true could add a stack trace of the error.

Comment: "I found on internet was that it is problem with XML conversion that is supposedly already resolved." additionally if you found some information on the issue you should share the source link and details so others can avoid redoing that part of the investigation. Note that the solution for other software may not be relevant for your Mule version.

Comment: I have added missing information as you requested. I did find out that error message I found was actually not about my case in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try upgrading the Web Service Consumer from current version 1.6.6 to latest version 1.6.7. It should resolve the printing of that error message.

Comment: I ran check for updates and it returned nothing so I am guessing I already have newest version.

Comment: In the log I see you are using 1.6.6. The release notes list 1.6.7 as the last release. Studio may not be yet updated to 1.6.7. Just change the version manually in the pom.

Comment: Thank you, you were correct once again :D